# How to delete existing git user completely?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my branch into remote but git says I can push as I don't have permission.

```
remote: Permission to zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend.git denied to mbilal003.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have changed git `user name` and `email` with new user. I have confirm that by `get config user.name` it shows `frontexpert`. But when I try to push, you can see in error about that git trying to push by username `mbilal003`. How could I remove that user and push change into remote with new user.

`git remote -v show`

```
origin  https://github.com/zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend (push)
upstream        https://github.com/zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend.git (push)
```

`git config -l | grep ^credential`

```
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
...skipping...
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
credential.helper=manager
pull.rebase=false
user.name=frontexpert
user.email=frontexport1987@gmail.com
core.editor="C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --wait
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
credential.helper=wincred
...skipping...
credential.helper=manager
pull.rebase=false
user.name=frontexpert
user.email=frontexport1987@gmail.com
core.editor="C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --wait
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
credential.helper=wincred
credential.helperselector.selected=store
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
submodule.active=.
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=frontexpert
user.email=frontexport1987@gmail.com
remote.upstream.url=https://github.com/zoegod911/arcane_arcade-frontend.git
remote.upstream.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
branch.homepage-redesign.remote=origin
branch.homepage-redesign.merge=refs/heads/homepage-redesign
credential.username=frontexpert
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing how your git remotes and credentials are set up. `git remote -v show; git config -l | grep ^credential`

Comment: Double check your ssh key.

Comment: @ephemient i edit question and added result of these commands

Comment: Somehow, the `| grep ^credential` part didn't filter the expected lines. Can you show only the lines that start with `credential` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in addition to changing `your name` and `email`, you may also need to change your credentials:

You use:

`git config credential.username "new_username"`

Comment: The `user.name` and `user.email` settings are entirely irrelevant here: these settings are used when you make new commits, but not when you run `git push` or `git fetch`. The credential settings are important, though. The problem with the credentials stuff is that every OS, and even release-of-OS, can change which credential parts matter...